# in C, what is default value for "static char" type

Tags: c

for example

```
static char all_data;
```

without initializing value to it. what is the default value? Or is it a Undefined Behavior?

I tried on my gcc-4.6 the answer is 0.

Thanks.

Comment: it should be 0 as per C standard.

Comment: For the `static char` it should be `0`; for a `static char *` however...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's still 0 (which is not necessarily represented in memory as all 0 bits).

Comment: @JimBalter, "which is not necessarily represented in memory as all 0 bits". Did not understand this. AFAIK, the static variables are zero'ed by `memset` (or something functionally similar to it). I don't know of a case, where any pointer may be NULL, but may have some of its bits set.

Comment: @anishsane (the equivalent of) memset is only used in implementations where it can be (which includes all implementations you are familiar with). That you don't know of other implementations doesn't mean there are none; see http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per C99:

```
If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
then:
— if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
— if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
— if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
— if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
rules.
```

Answer (score 3):

According to C standard static variables are by default initialized to zero. But it's a good practice to always initialize it explicitly. In [this](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=210) link there is a para named "Initialization" you will find your necessary information there.

Comment: That's not good practice in any organization I've belonged to. It is, however, good practice to provide explicit initializers in the definition.

Comment: initialize after declaration?

Comment: Sorry, wrong word choice. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

open-std.org: [ISO/IEC 9899:TC2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) tells us:

> if an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
>   then ... if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero

(page 126)

The `char` type is an arithmetic type. You are guaranteed initialization to `0`.